# System.Text.Json serializes/deserialize nullable reference types to "{}" as opposed to "null"

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

Trying to convert an old ASP.NET Core project from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json but it changes the behavior of nullable reference type conversion. System.Text.Json serializes/deserialize nullable reference types to "{}" as opposed to "null". How do I fix it? I want to get rid of Newtonsoft.Json.

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Here is the type for that List `public IList<IDictionary<string, object>> List { get; set; }`. The actual value type is `DBNull`.

### System.Text.Json

```
{
    "data": {
        "list": [
            {
                "headers": [],
                "list": [
                    {
                        "id": "3faab29e-982d-ccb9-197b-08db24ef09e7",
                        "contractType": "Basis",
                        "tEvent": "Edit",
                        "Basis": 0.0000,
                        "fees": {},
                        "FlatPrice": {},
                        "theirContract": {}
                    },
```

### Newtonsoft.Json

```
{
    "data": {
        "list": [
            {
                "headers": [],
                "list": [
                    {
                        "id": "3faab29e-982d-ccb9-197b-08db24ef09e7",
                        "contractType": "Basis",
                        "tEvent": "Edit",
                        "Basis": 0.0000,
                        "fees": null,
                        "FlatPrice": null,
                        "theirContract": null
                    },
```

Comment: @madreflection "The actual value type is DBNull." I assume NewtonSoft has special handling for that in contrast to System.Text.Json. Presumably you need to write a specialized Converter that knows about DBNull and translates that to an actual null.

Comment: Or if possible fix it before putting DBNull into your dictionary by replacing it with an actual null.

Comment: "I want to get rid of Newtonsoft.Json."  Very bad idea! Maybe you will have to start looking for a new job too, since the current project will be collapsed very soon.

Comment: @Serge Its just a serializer? No need to panic.

Comment: @Ralf Time will tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As at the time of writing, `System.Text.Json` [does not have built-in support for `DBNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0#types-without-built-in-support).

Instead, you can write a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-7.0) to handle `DBNull` values, by overriding the converter's [`Write()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.write?view=net-7.0#system-text-json-serialization-jsonconverter-1-write(system-text-json-utf8jsonwriter-0-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)) method to print out the JSON literal `null` instead:

```
public class DBNullJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DBNull> 
{ 
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) 
    { 
        return typeToConvert == typeof(DBNull); 
    } 
 
    public override DBNull Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    { 
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    } 
 
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DBNull value, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    { 
        // write the JSON literal null
        writer.WriteNullValue(); 
    } 
}
```

Then, pass this converter to the `JsonSerializerOptions` of your `JsonSerializer`:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new DBNullJsonConverter());

// you should get null for fields of type DBNull here
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(someObject, options);
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0#types-without-built-in-support) there is not built-in support for DBNull.

You have to use a custom converter:

```
class DBNullConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<DBNull>
{
    public override DBNull Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();           
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DBNull value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteNullValue();
    }
}
```

Then add it to the options:

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters =
    {
        new DBNullConverter()
    }
}
```